# django RQ / rq scheduler - Possible to disable job timeout?

Tags: django, redis

Once in a while, I have a job that requires much longer processing than anticipated so i'd like to disable timeout if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `job_timeout` when enqueuing a job and that'll be preserved, default timeout is 3 minutes (180), I believe your function is taking more than three minutes.

> By default, jobs should execute within 180
> seconds. After that, the worker kills the work horse and puts the job
> onto the failed queue, indicating the job timed out.
>
> If a job requires more (or less) time to complete, the default timeout
> period can be loosened (or tightened), by specifying it as a keyword
> argument to the enqueue() call, like so:
>
> q = Queue() q.enqueue(mytask, args=(foo,), kwargs={'bar': qux},
> job_timeout=600)  # 10 mins

https://github.com/rq/rq/blob/6bfd47f735de3f297ba3c8f59d5e2dcfa1987107/docs/docs/results.md#L88

Comment: im using rq scheduler / django_rq.. i tried passing timeout, but it doesn't seem to honor it (i.e. it times out at timeout specified in settings.py)

t_delta = {"seconds":2}
job = scheduler.enqueue_in(timedelta(**t_delta), some_func, timeout=None)

Comment: You're passing timeout as None, it should be some absolute value other than None and default.

Comment: yeah, im trying to disable it.. not set a value (i.e no timeout)

Comment: no sir, you're doing it wrong, you can't reset time, you can just change it from the default value.